# I'm getting an Array out of bounds exception after executing this code:

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to perform a bubble sort and sort the array into descending:

```
public void sortDescending(Cities arr[], int n) {
    String temp[]; //stores sorted array
    temp = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int len1 = arr[j].name.length();
            int len2 = arr[j + 1].name.length();
            if (len1 < len2) {
                temp[j] = arr[j + 1].name;
                temp[j + 1] = arr[j].name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<n;j++){` then `arr[j+1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void sortDescending(Cities arr[], int n){
    String temp[]; //stores sorted array
    temp = new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++){//change this code as its checking array for j and j+1. so if you run you loop till n it will check array for n+1 hence array index out of bound error
        int len1 = arr[j].name.length();
        int len2 = arr[j+1].name.length();
        if(len1 < len2 ){
            temp[j] =  arr[j+1].name;
            temp[j+1] = arr[j].name;
        }
    }
 }
```

//for bubble sort use below code

```
void bubbleSort(Cities arr[], int n)
{
    //int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                // swap temp and arr[i]
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
}
```

If you need any thing in return from this function just return array.
You dont have to create temp array for bubble sort

Comment: If its solved your issue, Accept the answer and up-vote it. Its motivate user to keep contributing.

Comment: The last element value which is printed shows null though, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger  I feel like sorted array will not be a problem as counter will go on. Its like bubble sort. right ?

Comment: @SupriyaHonawale where is your print statement. please post full code as i can not find null related issue in this block of code

Comment: @SupriyaHonawale this is working? HOW? what happens if say half the array is already sorted (`len1 >= len2`)? I am pretty sure the (sorted) names will not be transferred to `temp` (and `arr` is not changed, and nothing being returned)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I got your point. I have added code for bubble sort too. last time I missed the temp array. Thanks for pointing out.